# Why doesn't Firemonkey create an application handle when there is a string in the global atom table that is the same as the modulename

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, handle, delphi-10.1-berlin

Situation : 
there is a string in the global atom table  that is the same as my application. My Application does not create an application handle and I get an invalid window handle.

code from the FMX.Platform.Win

```
procedure TPlatformWin.CreateAppHandle;
var
  //...
begin
  //...
  AtomName := ModuleName;
  AppAtom := GlobalFindAtom(PChar(AtomName));
  if AppAtom > 0 then begin
    FApplicationHWND := 0; // FApplicationHWND = 0 and I get "invalid window handle" 
  end else begin
    // FApplicationHWND is created
```

I have an old application where the exe has the same name. After closing it appearantly leaves a string in the globalatomtable 'COM'. After closing this old application. I cannot longer open the new application because it keeps finding this 'COM' in the gloabal atom table, resulting in an ampty application handle and invalid window handles.

If I put the code in comments the application start perfect with a valid application handle.

```
//  AtomName := ModuleName;
//  AppAtom := GlobalFindAtom(PChar(AtomName));
//  if AppAtom > 0 then begin
//    FApplicationHWND := 0;
//  end else
```

Comment: Embarcadero has written some really questionable code in recent years, but I think this has to take the cake. Why would this be needed? FMX doesn't even create the Atom that is being looked for. This code makes no sense. That said, you can call `FMX.Platform.Win.RegisterApplicationHWNDProc()` to provide a callback function that returns its own `HWND`, bypassing `CreateAppHandle()` completely. But that leaves `FApplicationHWND` set to 0, which breaks a few things that use `FApplicationHWND` directly instead of using the `ApplicationHWND()` function. FMX is not designed very well, IMHO.

Comment: I filed a bug report with Embarcadero: [RSP-15232 TPlatformWin.ApplicationHWND property is broken](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15232)

Comment: The other application is a VCL application last built in delphi XE I think. So maybe it used to write to the atom table. But I agree that it should not matter to the new application and the application handle.

Comment: Thx for the feedback and the bug report.This problem also caused another bug when no application handle was assigned. Resulting in 'Invalid window handles' so this is kind of a related bug report : https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15225?filter=-2

Comment: "FMX is not designed very well" <- Winner: *Understatement of the Year (2016)*  :)

Comment: Embarcadero developers need to understand atoms before using them, and they need a very specific reason for using them.  This isn't the first time they've created a bug due to their usage of atoms.  One major leak was fixed in XE3:  http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90511